# Access method from ApplicationController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am attempting to use a gem that requires me to access the current user that is logged in through a controller extension.  Here is my ApplicationController with what I thought should work:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all
  protect_from_forgery
  set_current_tenant_to(current_user.member)

  private

     def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
     end

     helper_method :current_user

     def require_user
       unless current_user
        flash[:notice] = "You must be logged in to access this page"
        redirect_to '/login'
        return false
       end
     end
end
```

This fails on the set_current_tenant_to with "undefined local variable or method `current_user' for ApplicationController:Class".

Is there any way to get access to the current_user method through a controller extension?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is with the scope: if you're defining current user as an instance method, it will be available to all instances of the controller (which are created on every url request), but you are trying to use it as a class method.

So to define it as a class method:

```
def self.current_user
  ...
end
```

but it has no sense without the request, and it has even less sense because classes will be cashed in production, and set_current_tenant_to will be called only once on server start.

PS sorry for necroposting, I've just seen there is no answer here

Answer (score 1):

Your helper is in the private section -- you want that outside of the private block

Comment: Hi John,

I have tried that as well and get the same results. It happens not only in my ApplicationController but in any controller I try it in.

Thanks again!

Comment: Did you reload after you made the change?  You can't access `current_user` from another controller if it's in the `private` block of the ApplicationController

Comment: IWasRobbed is right on -- reloading it is necessary. All the other controllers *do* inherit from ApplicationController, right?

Comment: I have updated my code to the following and restarted the server.

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :all
  protect_from_forgery
  set_current_tenant_to(current_user.member)  
  
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
   helper_method :current_user
end

With this I still have the same issue:
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method `current_user' for ApplicationController:Class)

I have access to current_user outside of this.